# Laravel 5.5 autoload a function for each page without calling that function for each controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm going to create a dynamic left navigation (menu) for each users. I have already created the database table for the same. Also, I have generated the menu structure based on the user logged in. The Left navigation is located as partial view (leftnav.blade.php). I'm currently passing the left nav data (generated from database values) to the view as like:

```
$data['tree'] = $this->generateSiteTree(0); // left nav generated
$data['bla] = 'bla bla etc';
return view('Administrator.permission.index', $data);
```

But, I do not want to generate the menu structure for each page individually by writing the same code again for another controller. 
I know how to create Helper function. 
My question is - how to automatically call the function for each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

```
public function boot()
    {
        View::share('tree', $this->generateSiteTree(0));
        View::share('bla', 'bla bla etc');
    }
```

Comment: I understand that I have to write the function the boot method of AppServiceProvider. Can I include query there like: \DB::table('adminmenumaster')->where('adminMenuParentId', '=', $startAt)->get() ??

Answer (score 3):

You can create a view composer to populate data in your ONLY in your left nav. See this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` insert this code inside your boot function:

```
View::composer('leftnav', function ($view) {
    $view->with('tree', $this->users->count());
});
```

Don't forget to put this at the top:

```
use Illuminate\View\View;
```